# How to find all ideals of $A = \Bbb Z\times K,$ where $K$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

This is the task: Find all ideals of $A = \Bbb Z\times K$ where $K$ is a field, with addition and multiplication defined by $$(m,x)+(n,y)=(m+n,x+y)$$ and $$(m,x)\cdot (n,y)=(mn, my+nx+xy).$$

I have no idea how to find the ideals. I know what an ideal is, but I have not found how can I accurately find all ideals (is there no algorithm or something like this?).

Comment: What is $Z$? What do you mean with $Z * K$?

Comment: Z - integers of course, * is the Cartesian product (A × B)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** For any ideal $I \subset \Bbb Z$, you'll find that $\{(m,x): m \in I, x \in K\}$ will be an ideal of $\Bbb Z \times K$.  In fact, these will be the only ideals.

---

Edit: I missed something. If $K$ is a field of characteristic $p$, then $mp\Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ is also an ideal for any $m \in \Bbb N$.  I think that with that, we have now accounted for all ideals.

---

Explanation in other words:

For example, take $K = \Bbb Z_p$, the integers modulo $p$.  For every $m \in \Bbb Z$, the set $m\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_p$ will be an ideal of $A = \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z_p$.  The set $pm\Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ will also be an ideal.  There are no other ideals in $A$.

Comment: A nice way to interpret this ring is to consider $(m,x)$ as the "formal sum" $m + x$.

Comment: I must prove that if (m,n) is in ideal of A and (a,b)is in A then (m,n)*(a,b) is int ideal too???

Comment: @J_G I don't understand your question

Comment: How can I prove that this thing is ideal and there is no others?

Comment: @J_G the reason that I have given you a hint as opposed to a complete answer is that I expect you to try to figure that out on your own.  If you have thought about it for some time and are still stuck, I'll be happy to provide more guidance.

Comment: Ok. K is a field, so there are only two ideals - (0) and K.  xZ is all ideals of Z (x is in Z). There are 3 points to prove that (m,n) is an ideal:

Comment: 1. it is not empty

Comment: 2. if (m,n) and (a,b) are in ideal so (m,n)-(a,b) is in ideal to

Comment: @J_G you don't have to take me through your whole process.  Just give it a try, and tell me where you get stuck

Comment: 3.  if (m,n) is in ideal and (a,b) is in A so (m,n)*(a,b) is in ideal to

Comment: ok. I take ((m, {0})) - ideal and (a,b) is in A. So, (x, 0) is in this ideal. (x,0)*(a,b)=(ax, xb). its obviously that ax is in ideal m, but how to prove that xb is in {0}???

Comment: @J_G Reread my answer; I've changed it a bit.  We can only guarantee that $xb = 0$ (for an integer $x$) if $x$ is a multiple of the characteristic of $K$.

Comment: I dont understand this edit. My english is not so well. Could you explain it in other words?

Answer (score 1):

For better clarity, I'll denote by $\def\1{\mathbf{1}}\1$ the identity of $K$.

The set
$$
I_{\mathbb{Z}}=\{m\in\mathbb{Z}:(m,x)\in I\text{, for some }x\in K\}
$$
is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, if $(m,x),(n,y)\in I$, then $(m+n,x+y)\in I$, so $m+n\in I_{\mathbb{Z}}$. If $(m,x)\in I$ and $n$ is an integer, then $(m,x)(n,0)=(mn,nx)\in I$ and $mn\in I_{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Therefore $I_{\mathbb{Z}}=a\mathbb{Z}$, for a unique $a\ge0$.

Let $(m,x)\in I$. If $m\1+x$ is invertible, then we can solve for $y$ in
$$
(m,x)(1,y)=(m,z)
$$
for every $z\in K$, because we can choose $y=(m\1+x)^{-1}(z-x)$. So, if for every $m\in I_{\mathbb{Z}}$ there exists $x\in K$ with $(m,x)\in I$ and $m\1+x$ invertible, then $I=I_{\mathbb{Z}}\times K$.

It remains to analyze the case when, for every $m\in I_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and every $x\in K$ such that $(m,x)\in I$, we have $m\1+x$ not invertible, which means $x=-m\1$.

Thus $I=\{(am,-am\1):m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, where $I_{\mathbb{Z}}=a\mathbb{Z}$. Is this an ideal? It is certainly closed under sums and contains zero. For arbitrary $(n,y)$, we have
$$
(am,-am\1)(n,y)=(amn,amy-amn\1-amy)=(amn,-amn\1)
$$

Comment: I was thinking whether we could look at rings of the form $S:=(\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z})\times R$, where $R$ is a unital ring of characteristic 
 $d$ dividing $k$ ($d,k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ with the convention that $0\mid 0$), with addition and multiplication defined in the same manner as the OP's definition.  For sure, $\{0\}\times J$, where $J$ is an ideal of $R$ is an ideal of $S$.  For any integer $h\geq0$ such that $d\mid h$ and $h\mid k$, $(h\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z})\times 0$ is an ideal of $S$.  There are other ideals, but can we characterize them all based on what we know about $R$?

Comment: @Batominovski The part where the equation is solved for $y$ is decisive in the classification for the case at hand. The more general problem is when $R$ is an $A$-algebra ($A$ a commutative ring), but I don't think there is a classification.